# What tool can I use to transcode my videos to Webm?

Tags: video, codec

What tools can I use to transcode my videos to Webm?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the official site for the WebM project?

http://www.webmproject.org/

Comment: Good tip. It looks like (limited) support for FFmpeg, which should do the trick.